# I get a email without the form information, why?

Tags: php, email

If I submit the form I only get an email in my mailbox, with no information. How can i fix this?

PHP code:

```
<?php
$to      = 'julius.kroon@gmail.com';
$subject = 'new costumer';
if(isset($_POST['title'])){ $title = $_POST['title']; }
if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; }
if(isset($_POST['companyname'])){ $companyname = $_POST['companyname']; }
if(isset($_POST['mail'])){ $mail = $_POST['mail']; }
if(isset($_POST['extrapages'])){ $extrapages = $_POST['extrapages']; }
if(isset($_POST['sow'])){ $sow = $_POST['sow']; }
$title = null;
$name = null;
$companyname = null;
$mail = null;
$extrapages = null;
$sow = null;
$message ="
title = $title
name = $name
companyname = $companyname
mail = $mail
extra pages = $extrapages
site on web = $sow";
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

HTML code:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
    <em>Last name:</em></br>
    <select name="title" id="title">
        <option>Mr.</option>
        <option>Mrs.</option>
        <option>Dr.</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" size="25" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Last name"><p /><br>

    <em>company name:</em></br>
    <input type="text" size="25" name="companyname" id="companyname" placeholder="Company Name"><p /><br>

    <em>Email:</em></br>
    <input type="text" size="25" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="email"><p /><br>

    <em>how many extra pages:</em><br>
    <select name="extrapages" id="extrapages">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
    </select><br><br>

    <em>Would you like us to put your site on the internet?</em><br>
    <input type="radio" name="sow" id="sow" value="Yes">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="sow" id="sow" value="No">No<br><br>
    <input type="Submit" value="Send!">
</form>
```

If I submit the form I only get the following text in my email:

> title =
>   name =
>   companyname =
>   mail =
>   extra pages =
>   site on web =

What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: You are setting all variables to null after isset condition. Remove that.

Comment: You're getting the right output i.e., You're doing the data null !

Comment: :D remove those null assigments

Comment: now i get the error :Undefined variable. how do i solve this error?

Comment: Put all those null assignments before isset condition

Comment: sorry i am just a php starter. but how do put all the null assignments before the isset condition? (i am not very good at english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your first problem:

> ```
> enctype="text/plain"
> ```

PHP doesn't support that encoding of form data and won't populate `$_POST` if given data in that format. Remove it.

Your second problem is here:

> ```
> $title = null;
> $name = null;
> $companyname = null;
> $mail = null;
> $extrapages = null;
> $sow = null;
> ```

After collecting the data from `$_POST`… you throw it away. Don't do that. Remove those lines.

> now i get the error :Undefined variable. how do i solve this error?

This is covered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index).